# why some programs needs -h and other no

Tags: command-line, options

I know that is not a exciting question, but yet I don't understand why some programs needs

```
program -h
```

and other

```
program --help
```

sometimes is very boring recognize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, programs should have both options. The `-h` is the "short form" and `--help` is "long form".

Short form command options are usually one or two characters while long form options are more descriptive (such as `yum update -y` and `yum update --assume-yes` meaning "assume yes to all questions").

Programs that don't use both usually are non-standard utilities.

Comment: What standard? posix doesn't mandate it: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02

Answer (score 1):

I guess if `-h` makes sense for something else other than help, especially when program has lots of options so you're pretty much using a lot of options with those switches, it would make sense to put something as help on `--help`.